# find all users id and distance into database within 100 meter range by my current location(latitude, longitude)?

Tags: sql, google-maps, distance, latitude-longitude

i have the following data:

1. Current location
   a. Latitude
   b. Longitude
2. userid

in my database i have latitude and longitude of all users

i want to find out all users within range of 100 meter from my current location.

i have used the some of the example but they are showing distance of 9 meter for the same latitude and longitude up to 6 digit decimal place in latitude and longitude.

i ahve used the following code

`SELECT * , ((((acos( sin( ($lat * pi() /180 )) * sin((`latitude`* pi() /180) ) + cos( ( $lat * pi() /180 )) * cos((`latitude`* pi() /180)) * cos((( $lon -`longitude`) * pi() /180 )))) *180 / pi()) *60 * 1.1515)*1.60934) AS`distance`FROM tablename where radar_status`<>'0' and having `distance`<'0.100' ORDER BY `distance` ASC limit 1,10
Thankyou

Comment: I thought about this again with your 6 decimal place agreement - do you mean the 7th decimal place doesn't agree? With a 10 metre error in *same* location thats a 1e-12 error or rounding in the formula. I get that from aces(1-error)*RadiusEarth = 10 metres. Is your error smaller than error here? i.e. workout the error before applying acos . With zero error you should get the required result but worth checking what kind of tolerances you are likely to get. It may just be that your data doesn't give you the granularity you need...

Answer (score 3):

Please check the result or check the link

http://forums.asp.net/t/1325947.aspx/1

http://janmatuschek.de/LatitudeLongitudeBoundingCoordinates#PolesAnd180thMeridian

if you pass the current user's  latitude, longitude and the distance you wants to find, then the following query will do the stuff.

```
SELECT * FROM(SELECT *,(((acos(sin((@latitude*pi()/180)) * sin((Latitude*pi()/180))+cos((@latitude*pi()/180)) * cos((Latitude*pi()/180)) * cos(((@longitude - Longitude)*pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515*1.609344) as distance FROM Distances ) t  WHERE distance <= @distance
```

please check this also

```
$distance = 10;
$latitude = 37.295092;
$longitude = -121.896490;
$sql = "SELECT loc.*, (((acos(sin(($latitude*pi()/180)) * sin((`latitude`*pi()/180))+cos(($latitude*pi()/180)) * cos((`latitude`*pi()/180)) * cos((($longitude - `longitude`)*pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515) AS `distance` FROM table_with_lonlat_ref loc HAVING distance < $distance"
```

Comment: Hi @Prionce can you let me know above $distance = 10; is it meter or KM or other ??

Comment: In the above query we we multiply it by '*1.609344)' to make it in mile, in the below query we do not multiply so the above query for distance in mile and below query for KM. @Kevin G Flynn

Answer (score 0):

there are few formula to do this and looks like you are using the spherical law of cosines. You seem to be converting to radians which is good and looks like you are converting from Earth radius to km fine too - but check out this below:

1) Your SQL setup is in radians by default I assume?
sin(pi/2)=1 etc.

2) I think you are over converting to radians with an extra pi/180 in your query. Try this one as the meat of your query.

try this:

ACOS(  SIN( $lat1*pi()/180 ) * SIN ( latitude*pi()/180 ) + COS( $lat*pi()/180 ) * COS ( latitude*pi()/180 ) * COS ( ($lon-longitude)*pi()/180 ) )*63.71

Which can get tricky to figure out the brackets but is

```
ACOS( SIN(lat1)*sin(lat2) + COS(lat1)*cos(lat2)*cos(lon1-lon2) ) * RadiusEarth
```

and all angles in radians. Radius Earth in same units as your query filter, i.e. km as you filter on <0.100

Your *60*1.51 with another 1.60 elsewhere could be giving you a spurious result - are these scale factors giving you something other than the Earth Radius?

...Nick

Comment: hi @nickl, can you edit the query that you are saying, Thanks.

Comment: Oh and check this out if you're still drawing a blank...  http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html